# EWS Request meeting as a user to book a room

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

For this server, when a user attempts to book a room in Exchange, the room auto replies with an accept/decline. I am trying to replicate this process in EWS - using a service account to request a room meeting with a user attendee and a room resource. In order to have the room auto-reply to the user, and not the service account, do I need to use impersonation, or is there any other process? I am using php-ews for this, but any help in any language or what the SOAP request should contain would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could request meeting using the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"       
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"       
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <m:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
         <m:Items>
            <t:CalendarItem>
               <t:Subject>Status Meeting</t:Subject>
               <t:Body BodyType="Text">The purpose of this meeting is to discuss project status.</t:Body>
               <t:Start>2009-03-01T17:00:00Z</t:Start>
               <t:End>2009-03-01T19:00:00Z</t:End>
               <t:Location>Conf Room</t:Location>
              <t:RequiredAttendees>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>user1@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>user2@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
               </t:RequiredAttendees>
               <t:OptionalAttendees>
                  <t:Attendee>
                     <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>user3@contoso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                     </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Attendee>
               </t:OptionalAttendees>
            </t:CalendarItem>
         </m:Items>
      </m:CreateItem>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For more information, please refer to these links:

[Creating appointments and meetings by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633661(v%3Dexchg.80))

[Exchange Web Services Create Meeting Request Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731303/exchange-web-services-create-meeting-request-working-example)